# How to resolve return assignment issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this error in my code

`Arrow function should not return assignment no-return-assign`

The code giving me the error is this

```
await DB.Place.find(
      match, // key to filter
      (err, doc) => (listOfObjects = doc),
    )
```

I would like to know how to fix this as I tried this solution

```
listOfObjects === doc
```

But in this way is breaking my solution and is not giving me back the results of the find

Comment: What are you actually trying to do then?  What is `listOfObjects`?  Where and how is it defined?  Do you mean to actually return `doc` and assign `listOfObjects` outside of the await?  Try `listOfObjects = await DB.Place.find(match);`.

Comment: The "error" is from eslint or eshint or something like that; there's no JavaScript syntax issue. Either change the linter setup or re-do the function so that there's no assignment operator in the return expression.

Answer (score 1):

Its look like the code is good, try this

```
listOfObjects = await DB.Place.find(
      match, // key to filter
      (err, doc) => ( return doc),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is completely describing the problem. It is because your linter settings do not allow to make an assignment and return the result of assignment in the single string.
It can be solved usually by return of updated variable after new value is assigned.

```
(err, doc) => {
listOfObjects = doc
return listOfObjects)
```

Linter helps you to avoid mixing '=' with '==' what may cause unpredictable and more likely wrong behavior of you function